# Freeradius Proxy: packet forwarding by source address

Tags: proxy, packet, forward, radius, freeradius

I need some suggestion on a freeradius proxy configuration.

The proxy works fine in a "simple" configuration (with a single destination server or with a single destination per realm), but I ve the needed to forward the packets by **its source address** because, in every case, the realm is the same.

So, if user "john@REALM" come from ip addr 10.20.30.40, the proxy should forward packet to SERVER-A; if ***the same user*** "john@REALM" come from ip addr 40.30.20.10 the proxy should forward packet to SERVER-B.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion/idea,
Gianluca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
split_username_nai
if (Stripped-User-Domain == 'REALM') {
    switch "%{Packet-Src-IP-Address}" {
        case 10.20.30.40 {
            update control {
                Proxy-To-Realm := 'SERVER-A'
            }
        }
        case 40.30.20.10 {
            update control {
                Proxy-To-Realm := 'SERVER-B'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`split_username_nai` is a policy which is in the default configuration of the server, it'll break apart a username string into Stripped-User-Name and Stripped-User-Domain.

We check the value of Stripped-User-Domain, to see that it's 'REALM' then switch over the Src-IP-Address of the RADIUS packet (this could be any attribute, like NAS-IP-Address or Called-Station-ID), and set the Proxy-To-Realm attribute appropriately.

After the request leaves the authorize section, the server will proxy the request to the appropriate realm.